# Stumped by jquery.find() method for parsing JSON from Wiktionary API

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using [this code](https://gist.github.com/nichtich/674522) as a starting point to parse JSON returned via the Wiktionary API. I want to customize this code to extract just the IPA pronunciation info for any word. I'd hoped to write it all myself but was getting nowhere so I started messing around with the code linked above. I understand almost all of it, but where I hit a wall is with this:

```
$("#wikiInfo").find('a:not(.references a):not(.extiw):not([href^="#"])').attr('href',
function() {
    return baseURL + $(this).attr("href");
    }
);
```

I understand the `.find()` method, but the chain of `:not()` selectors and what appears to be a compound selector `a:not(.references a)` filtering all links with class 'references' inside links? Huh?

Do the successive `:not()` selectors apply an additional filter? I'm totally lost. Can someone please explain what's going on in the above pasted code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector says find all the andchors 'a' who aren't inside and element with the class '.references' and has not the class `extiw` and an attribute `href` who starts by `#` :

```
'a:not(.references a):not(.extiw):not([href^="#"])'
```

> **a**:  Select all the Anchors.
>
> **:not(.references a)** : Except the ones inside elements with class `references`.
>
> **:not(.extiw)** : And who hasn't a class `extiw`.
>
> **:not([href^="#"])** : Without an attribute `href` that start with `#`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Zakaria. That's very helpful! So to be clear, this is only finding anchors, not all `<a></a>` tags?

Comment: _anchor = `<a></a>`_ .. The selector will select the `<a>` tags who satisfy the condition specified in the different `not`'s.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. So if I understand correctly, the following `.attr()` method is taking the selected anchors and setting their `"href"` attributes to point back to wiktionary while keeping all of the target anchors inside my domain so they work as expected in the newly added Wiktionary data on my page?